# How to animate a list with stagger - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 7 and I am trying to animate a list of components with stagger. When the list is initialized the animation works correctly, but when the values in the list change, the animation is performed on the old values of the list and then the new ones appear without animation.

In my component.ts I have:

```
export const itemAnimation = [
  style({
    opacity: 0
  }),
  stagger(30, [
    animate(
      '300ms 100ms ease-in',
      style({
        opacity: 1
      })
    )
  ])
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animExample', [transition('* => *', [query('.item', itemAnimation, { optional: true })])])
  ]
})
```

and in template:

```
<div [@animExample]="items">
  <div class=".item" *ngFor="let item of items">
     <app-example [data]="item"></app-example>
  </div>
 </div>
```

It seems that the animation is done on the old values of `*ngfor` and then the new components are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to work, but this could potentially be because of the way ngFor works.

By default angular doesn't know how to track changes in a collection and will re-render everything if something in collection changes, to fix that, you can try adding tracking function to your component.

```js
export const itemAnimation = [
  style({
    opacity: 0
  }),
  stagger(30, [
    animate(
      '300ms 100ms ease-in',
      style({
        opacity: 1
      })
    )
  ])
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animExample', [transition('* => *', [query('.item', itemAnimation, { optional: true })])])
  ]

  trackByItem(_: number, item: Item) {
    return item.id; // or something from item that would uniquely identify item within collection
  }
})
```

And then change your template code to:

```html
<div [@animExample]="items">
  <div class=".item" *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy:trackByItem">
     <app-example [data]="item"></app-example>
  </div>
</div
```

This is a guess. :)

Also, this is a very nice read illustrating how track helps with rendering: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

I based my assumptions on this blog post.